# Is there a way to add elements to this vector?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance, shared-ptr

I have a class `Column.h`, a template `ColumnImpl.h` and a `Tab.h`

```
class Column {
public:
    Column() {}
    virtual ~Column() {};
    virtual string getType() = 0;
};
```

```
template <typename T> class ColumnImpl : public Column {
public:
    ColumnImpl() : Column() {}
    void addElem(const T& elem_to_add);
protected:
    vector<T> _data;
};
```

```
class Tab {
public:
    Tab();
    ~Tab() {};
    template <typename S> void addElemToCol(const string & col_name, const S & data_to_add);
private:
    map<string, shared_ptr<Column>> _columns;

};
```

What I would like to do now, is adding elements to the template vector inside `ColumnImpl.h` using the method `addElem`, and then recalling it inside `addElemToCol`.

To do that I've tried (inside `addElemToCol`):

```
if (this->colIsPresent(col_name)) {
    const auto & it = _columns.find(col_name);
    it->second.get().
}
```

But here I realized I don't have the `addElem` method... How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT 1:**

This is how I'm checking the type and adding it into the vector:

```
int data;
data_stream >> data;
if (!data_stream.fail()) {
    if (target_database.tabIsPresent(tab_name)) {
        target_database.addElemToColOfTab(tab_name, col_name, data);
    }
```

This is a `Database` method:

```
    template <typename D> void addElemToColOfTab(const string & tab_name, const string & col_name, const D& data_to_add) {
        const auto & it_target_tab = _tables.find(tab_name);
        it_target_tab->second.addElemToCol(col_name, data_to_add);
    }
```

This is a `Tab` method:

```
template <typename S> void addElemToCol(const string & col_name, const S & data_to_add) {
    if (this->colIsPresent(col_name)) {
        const auto & it = _columns.find(col_name);
        switch (Type2Int(it->second->getType())) {
            case OptionInt: {
                ColumnImpl<int>* p_int = dynamic_cast<ColumnImpl<int> *>(it->second.get());
                if (p_int != nullptr) {
                    p_int->addElem(data_to_add);
                }
                break;
            }
            case OptionFloat: {...}
            // [...] All the other Columns
        }
    }
}
```

And every class `IntColumn`, `FloatColumn` has its own implementation:

```
void addElem(const int& elem_to_add) { _data.push_back(elem_to_add); } // this is for IntColumn
```

Comment: You can't without adding some virtual method to `Column`, or knowing what `T` is for the `ColumnImpl` instance.

Comment: I should add a virtual method to `Column` and then implement it into `ColumnImpl`?
(It should be a template method, am I right?)

Comment: Template member functions cannot be virtual.

Comment: You're right, I just got `'virtual' cannot be specified on member function templates`...
What can I do then?

Comment: I've tried to just not mark it as virtual and do what I needed to do... It seems to work, but I don't know if it's correct

Comment: If you know what `T` is for the specific `ColumnImpl` (wouldn't you have to in order to safely add stuff to it?) then you can `dynamic_cast<ColumnImpl<SomeType> *>(it->second.get())` and test if the result is not `nullptr`.

Comment: Ok, I've just read about dynamic_cast (I'm definitely not an expert as you may have understood) and it seems the perfect solution for my case!

Comment: @cdhowie I have many classes (`IntColumn`, `FloatColumn`, `CharColumn`, etc.)
Should I implement a different version for every class (in which every time I convert to a different type), or a template? (I think you said that making it with a template would not be secure because you don't know what you're putting into the vector)

Comment: Set aside the casting issue for a moment. What are you going to add to the vectors, and _how do you know_ that whatever you're going to add will be the right type?

Comment: The idea I had (since the element I'm going to add is the content of a stringstream) was doing  `my_stream >> my_var;` and then `if (!mystream.fail()) // add the element;`

Comment: What is the type of `my_var`? Do you know that it matches the type of whatever random `Column` you have a pointer to?

Comment: I was thinking about declaring a `my_var_int` if I'm adding a new int, or `my_var_char` for a char, etc. (inside a switch case)

Comment: Why not just use polymorphism for that? Can you show me the code where you're trying to perform this reading, including how you would determine the type of thing you want to add?

Comment: @cdhowie I edited the question with everything I've written so far to add an element... It returns two errors (`no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const int' to 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'` and `no matching function for call to 'ColumnImpl<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::addElem(const int&)'`) and I don't understand why

Comment: I guess what I've done is not the best option, I would really appreciate if you could help me fix this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because *all* of the switch blocks need to compile even if only one is taken.  `p_int->addElem(data_to_add);` can only compile when the type of `data_to_add` matches the corresponding `ColumnImpl` template type, and that's only true in *one* of the cases.

Since you know what `S` is, you don't actually need to go through any of the type-checking hoops; you can eliminate the `switch` altogether and just look for `ColumnImpl<S>`.  We can also have the function return a bool indicating whether adding the element was successful.

```
template <typename S>
bool addElemToCol(const string & col_name, const S & data_to_add) {
    const auto & it = _columns.find(col_name);
    if (it != _columns.end()) {
        auto ci = dynamic_cast<ColumnImpl<S> *>(it->second.get());
        if (ci != nullptr) {
            ci->addElem(data_to_add);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```